# Is there a way to track the css files I have invoked in cakephp?

Tags: css, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

This is my structure.

```
Layout --|
       View---|
            Element1, Element2, Element3
```

In Element1, 2, and 3, i have the following setup at the very top.

```
$this->append('pageCss');
echo $this->Html->css('left_navi/left_navi'); 
$this->end('pageCss');
```

There is redundancy depending on how the Element1, 2, and 3 are ordered in the View.

The Element1, 2, and 3 are also used in multiple Views.

I want to avoid invoking the css files unnecessarily. Is there a way to do something like:

```
if ($thisCssFileNotUsedBefore)
        echo $this->Html->css('left_navi/left_navi');
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ten1 at the cakephp irc channel for the clue.

I used the following solution:

1) First I wrote this custom Helper

```
<?php
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

class AssetsHelper extends AppHelper {

    public $cssFiles = array();

}
```

2) Make sure to call it as a Helper in the AppController

3) inside the various elements do this.

```
if (!in_array('left_navi/left_navi', $this->Assets->cssFiles)) {
    echo $this->Html->css('left_navi/left_navi'); 
    $this->Assets->cssFiles[] = 'left_navi/left_navi';
}
```